# VSE 1.5 to 3 Times Faster Scrubbing

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I would like to speed up video and audio playback in the video sequence editor. This would help me edit/chop up long videos since then I can hear any funny/important moments that should be in the final version. Final Cut achieves this effect by repeatedly pressing `l`, and I can still listen to audio when it's been sped up many times.

To achieve this same effect in Blender, I've tried using Power Sequencer and VSEQF as suggested in this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/197236/113533.
Unfortunately, it looks like both of these solutions cause warbly audio, making it easy to miss details in someone's speech. This YouTube video compares playback from a 1.75x speedup on Youtube to the first VSEQF speedup (aside from a few frames dropped because of the screen recorder, this is what the warped audio sounds like) https://youtu.be/sCou-A4IBTo.

Are there any other alternatives, or are there some settings I can use to further optimize playback? Thanks!

Comment: For long videos there are plenty of alternatives: use a  different video app. Blender is not a flexible or responsive video app. Download Davinci Resolve free and use it to edit. You can press the same L key to play, or play faster, J to play backwards.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33800 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130326 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7738 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31471

Comment: @susu thanks, I think I needed to hear that haha

Answer (score 2):

A bug was fixed in VSEQF, so now it works in 2.91: https://github.com/snuq/VSEQF

Use the numpad 4, 5 & 6 as J, K, L keys for playback speed:

[image]

Alternatively Scrubbing can be enabled in the Timeline Editor menu(but I think that'll only affect audio playing when dragging the playhead)

[image]

Comment: Cool! It wasn't very fair for me to only say "VSEQF is completely broken" so I'm sorry about that. That update fixed the problem I was having in Blender 2.83.5 where clicking anywhere threw an exception if I had VSEQF enabled. I was only able to speed up playback after updating from Blender 2.83.5 to 2.91. Also, pressing 6 twice seems to play the clip too quickly to keep the audio intact. Is there a config file I can noodle with?

Comment: If you need to go faster, you'll properly need to enable scrubbing in the Timeline Editor, and drag the playhead around. Image added to the comment above.

Comment: I'm okay with how fast I can play the video; however, I'm mostly concerned about the way the _audio_ sounds when speeding up playback. I added a YouTube video to my question to show how the audio gets warped, which is still an unsolved problem.

Comment: What you're asking seems to need to change the frame rate. I think in the past some add-ons did that, but changing the frame rate will mess up audio durations in relation to images.

Comment: Is such a change impossible to successfully implement in Blender currently? I ask this because other video editors such as Final Cut Pro have implemented this feature and editing still works flawlessly. Keeping the audio from breaking makes this feature critical to my editing workflow, so I would like to experiment with any add-ons that _might_ work, if nothing else.